# set initial state with react-redux outside of the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get my initial state into a component but I can't seem to get there. I'm setting my initial state to have a prop called `topic_drpDwn`, but in the `MonitoringPage` components, I don't see that show up in the state.

my index.js looks like this:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import './styles/styles.css'; //Webpack can import CSS files
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

let initialState     = {
    topic_drpDwn: ["nifi", "drop 2", "tsys"]
};

const store = configureStore(initialState);


render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

my MonitoringPage.js looks like this (this is where I'm expecting `this.props.topic_drpDwn`)

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as monitoringActions from '../../actions/monitoringActions';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class MonitoringPage extends React.Component {

    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            drplist: {drpTitle: "Sample topic selector", 
                      drpVal: ["tysys", "kafka-jmx", "nifi"]
                     }
        };

        this.onDropChange = this.onDropChange.bind(this);
    }

    onDropChange (event) {

        let drplist = Object.assign({}, this.state.drplist);

        console.log("drop changed")

        drplist.drpTitle = event;

        this.setState({drplist: drplist});
    }

    mkList (x) {

        return <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey={x}>{x}</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>

    }

    render (title) {

        let data = [1,2,3,4]

        console.log("data", title)


        console.log("state: ", this.state)

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Monitoring</h1>
                <h2>Monitoring Page under dev, example save button</h2>
                <input
                    type="text"

                     />
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="save" />
                <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton title={this.state.drplist.drpTitle} id="bg-vertical-1" onSelect={this.onDropChange}>
                    {this.state.drplist.drpVal.map(this.mkList)}
                </ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    console.log("initial state indx: ", JSON.stringify(state));
    return {
        monitoring: state.monitoring,
        topic_drpDwn: state.topic_drpDwn
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (MonitoringPage);
```

and configure store looks like this:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    console.log("initial state: ", initialState)
    initialState = initialState || { topic_drpDwn: [] }
    console.log("initial state2: ", initialState)
    return finalCreateStore(
        rootReducer, 
        initialState
    );
}
```

`console.log` in here does print what I put in `index.js` as initial state, but if I console log the `this.props` inside of the `MonitoringPage` components, I don't see the initial state show up...

```
console.log("props:", this.props)
{
  "children": null, 
  "history": {}, 
  "location": {
    "$searchBase": {
      "search": "", 
      "searchBase": ""
    }, 
    "action": "POP", 
    "hash": "", 
    "key": "9cjw6a", 
    "pathname": "/monitoring", 
    "query": {}, 
    "search": "", 
    "state": null
  }, 
  "monitoring": [], 
  "params": {}, 
  "route": {
    "path": "monitoring"
  }, 
  "routeParams": {}, 
  "routes": [
    {
      "childRoutes": [
        {
          "path": "onboarding"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "topicregistry"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "monitoring"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "about"
        }
      ], 
      "indexRoute": {}, 
      "path": "/"
    }, 
    {
      "path": "monitoring"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to follow this guide on how to set the initial state outside of a reducer.

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-supplying-the-initial-state

-----EDIT--------

I took out the context in the constructor and then logged the props right after and got this back:

```
{
  "children": null, 
  "history": {}, 
  "location": {
    "$searchBase": {
      "search": "", 
      "searchBase": ""
    }, 
    "action": "POP", 
    "hash": "", 
    "key": "9cjw6a", 
    "pathname": "/monitoring", 
    "query": {}, 
    "search": "", 
    "state": null
  }, 
  "monitoring": [], 
  "params": {}, 
  "route": {
    "path": "monitoring"
  }, 
  "routeParams": {}, 
  "routes": [
    {
      "childRoutes": [
        {
          "path": "onboarding"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "topicregistry"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "monitoring"
        }, 
        {
          "path": "about"
        }
      ], 
      "indexRoute": {}, 
      "path": "/"
    }, 
    {
      "path": "monitoring"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, my monitoringReducer looks like this:

```
export default function monitoringReducer (state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOPIC_SELECT':

            return Object.assign({}, state, topic_selected: [action.topic]);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and my rootReducer looks like this:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import monitoring from './monitoringReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    monitoring
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: You don't seem to follow mapStateToProps, read about it. MonitoringPage will only have the props you pass to it via mapStateToProps, nothing more. It can't access state directly. You are only passing monitoring as prop, and expecting topic_drpDown inside component. This is what was mentioned the previous time you asked the same question.

Comment: sorry...made a typo there...I just fixed it from `return {
            monitoring: state.monitoring
        };` to this `return {
            monitoring: state.monitoring,
            topic_drpDwn: state.topic_drpDwn
        };`...shouldn't I see `topic_drpDwn` in props then?

Comment: There is no need for context in constructor, remove that. Immediately after do console.log props. What do you see? I don't seem to see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Also, paste in the code for your reducer too.

Comment: I made an edit to show the changes....I see `topic_drpDwn` now in props but its undefined...

Comment: Have you defined finalCreateStore? AFAIK, it should be createStore(rootReducer, initialState). Of course you would have to import createStore from redux.

Comment: yep...I've defined it like this in `configureStore`......`const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(logger())
)(createStore)` and then export it like this...`export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    
    initialState = initialState || { topic_drpDwn: [] }
    
    return finalCreateStore(
        rootReducer, 
        initialState: initialState
    );
}`

Comment: so here is something I just saw...in my console I do see this: `Unexpected key "topic_drpDwn" found in initialState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "monitoring". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

Comment: Ah, that's helpful. You need to create a reducer named topic_drpDwn and dont have any cases in it, just return state, i.e empty array. Then pass this to root reducer. Seems redux needs to have information about the shape of state beforehand. Will need to read about this. Since you provided a reducer for `monitoring`, redux knows it is going to be one of the keys in state. Not the same with topic_drpDwn since you've not provided a reducer for it.

Comment: @AbhilashSingh that worked! I guess I don't understand why you need a reducer to set the initial state.

Answer (score 2):

What's the reducer for topic_drpDwn? Now there is only a monitoring reducer so all states are in state.monitoring. There is no reducer for state.topic_drpDwn. So redux is saying there is no reducer for state.topic_drpDwn.

Comment: I don't have one for `topic_drpDwn` but maybe I need to understand this more as I'm new to react. In order for me to set the initial state in redux, I need to have a reducer that does that as well? I thought that reducers returned a new state based on an action getting called, and maybe that is not correct?

Comment: You are right that reducers return new state based on the action, and more importantly, that's the only way to change a state. That's why you need a reducer to change topic_drpDwn. Otherwise you can never change topic_drpDwn. If it cannot be changed there is no point to have it in redux store.

Comment: so here is where I'm confused...in this tutorial video...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flXJA4Ftd1c&list=PLQDnxXqV213JJFtDaG0aE9vqvp6Wm7nBg&index=10...if you go to minute 2:27, you'll see he is setting the initial state and passing it into `let store = configureStore(initialState)`...that is what I'm trying to do to get it to work. Thats why I'm confused on why I need a reducer to set the initial state since the video is not using one.

Comment: In the video, at 2:27 he set the initial state with two states: todos and user. At 13:35 he created a reducer called todoReducer. At 18:20 he added the todoReducer by combineReducers() with the name 'todos'. Now this name is important because this name will be the name of the state that is handled by todoReducer. So the state which is handled by todoReducer will be 'state.todos'. So the name of it's initial state must also be todos, which you can see at 2:27.

Answer (score 1):

```
createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

What we are concerned here about is the second argument `preloadedState`.

Quoting from Redux `createStore` [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer).

> [`preloadedState`] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced `reducer` with [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html), this must be a plain
>   object with the **same shape as the keys passed to it**. Otherwise, you
>   are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

If you're using `combineReducers` and also have an initialState (or preloadedState) passed to `createStore`, makes sure the keys are exactly the same (not anything more, not anything less).

If this is violated, you might be probably seeing a warning in console:

```
Unexpected key "topic_drpDwn" found in initialState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "monitoring". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
```

**Solution:**

Use a single reducer to manage everything and pass it to `createStore`.

`finalCreateStore(reducer, initialState);`

`reducer` manages everthing. In your case, the state keys `monitoring` and `topic_drpDwn` are both handled by the same reducer.

But of course that is not what we desire in any App as we need to have abstract state slices. So lets split and create multiple reducers to manage a specific state slice. So you need to have a separate reducers for `topic_drpDwn` and `monitoring`. Then use `combineReducers` to create the `rootReducer` and pass it to `createStore`.

Answer (score -1):

Your should use react components lifecycle, and on componentWillMount() step call action, where you set initial state.

But better way is - setting initial state in reducer function as default argument:

```
const initialState = {
  someValue: {},
};

export default function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION_TYPE:
      return { ...state, someValue: action.payload };
  }
}
```